# Building Ionic Android App Throwing a Gradle Exception

Tags: angular, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

I am runing : `ionic cordova build android`
The following stacktrace is thrown:

```
  ...org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
  ...java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
  Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
             at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
```

I am behind a corporate proxy, could this be the issue?

Comment: Use `ionic cordova build android -- -d` to get verbose output. Clearly gradle is trying to connect to a server which is not listening on given port. https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let gradle access the internet via the proxy, in your `platforms/android` folder, in your `gradle.properties` file (create it if doesn't exist) add the following:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<your proxy ip or host>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=<your proxy port>
systemProp.http.proxyUser=<ur user if any>
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=<ur pass if any>
systemProp.https.proxyHost=<your proxy ip or host>
systemProp.https.proxyPort=<your proxy port>
systemProp.https.proxyUser=<ur user if any>
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=<ur passif any>
```

PS: please note that the file will be overwritten if you ever re-generated your platforms projects with `cordova/ionic`.